# How to bind data in custom picklist field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist

can anyone help me what I need to change to bind the data to a custom picklist. My component is called in a quick action and pass the record Id and get the lead details and show it on the page. However, the Salutation field does not bind the data.

Here is my js controller:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getLeadRecord from '@salesforce/apex/apexController.getLeadRecord';
import {getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import SALUTATION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Salutation';
import LEAD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';

export default class CustomLeadConversion extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // lead Id
    @track varLeadRecord = {};  //lead details
    @track leadObjectInfo;
    @track salutationValues;

    @wire(getLeadRecord, { leadId : '$recordId' })
    leadRecordDetails({ data, error }){
        if(data){
            this.varLeadRecord = data;
            console.log(this.varLeadRecord);
            console.log(this.varLeadRecord.Name);
            console.log(this.varLeadRecord.Id);
        }else if(error){

        }
    } 
           
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: LEAD_OBJECT })leadObjectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$leadObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', 
                               fieldApiName: SALUTATION_FIELD })
    wiredSalutationValues({data,error}){
        this.salutationValues = undefined;
        console.log('getPicklistValues');       
        if(data){                                    
            this.salutationValues = data.values;
            console.log(this.salutationValues);
        }else if(error){
            console.log('error');
        }
    };                                
}
```

here is my html file:

```
<template>
    <header class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Convert Lead</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">                                     
            
            <div class="c-container">                                
                <lightning-layout horizontal-align="stretch" multiple-rows="true" class="x-large">                   
                    <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" class="custom-box">                        
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Salutation</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <div class="slds-select_container">
                            <select class="slds-select" id="salutation">                                   
                                <option value="">--None--</option>
                                    <template for:each={salutationValues} for:item="salutationItem" >
                                        <option key={salutationItem.value} value={salutationItem.value}>
                                        {salutationItem.label}
                                        </option>
                                    </template>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                                                                                 
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </div>
                     
        
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={cancel}>Cancel</button>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleConvert} type="submit"> Convert</button>
        </footer>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add onchange listener on `select` tag. Once you get the selected value, you can assign it to any variable

```
<template>
    <select onchange={picklistChangeListener}>
        <option value="A">A value </option>
        <option value="B">B value </option>
        <option value="C">C value </option>
    </select>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    picklistChangeListener(event){
        console.log('Selected Value->'+event.target.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I need for it to work is, upon page load the value (lead salutation) is already selected in the picklist. I will try if there is a onload event here. BTW thanks @pranay